# PHP array return array vs passing as reference

Tags: performance, php

I'm not sure if Code Review is the proper SE site. If not, please point me in the right direction.

Let's assume we have a simple function, where you can pass an array and it will do some work on it. For simplicity sake, let's just assume you pass an array of integers to the function and it doubles them

I was wondering what's the correct way to do this, either by passing an array, and returning that array, which is AFAIK a pass by value in PHP and finally overwriting the initial variable, or simply passing a reference to that array.

**Option 1, pass by value:**

```
public function doubleValue(array $input): array
{
    foreach ($input as $key=>$val) {
        $input[$key] += $val;
    }

    return $input;
}

// called as $foo = $someClass->doubleValue($foo);
```

**Option 2, pass by reference:**

```
public function doubleValue(array &$input): void
{
    foreach ($input as $key=>$val) {
        $input[$key] += $val;
    }
}

// called as $someClass->doubleValue($foo);
```

My assumption would be, that pass by reference has to be faster, as it doesn't need to copy the array to that function, copy it back and assign it to the variable, but I could be wrong (at least ex. the built in `sort` function works this way). Are there any metrics about it? What is the recommended approach?

Comment: One of the rules here: Off-topic -> Lacks Concrete Context: _generic best practices are outside the scope of this site_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just never return an argument by reference. It is nearly as bad as using `global`. And even a memory management is not an excuse. In case your array is big, create a function that does the calculations, and then apply it to each element inside of an explicit loop.

Comment: My bad, I've forgot to remove the return statement and set the return type to void, when copying the example code >.< Now the second function actually takes an array by reference and doesn't return anything.

Comment: I did answer your question not your confused code.

Comment: I see, does PHP even enable you to return an argument by reference? I thought you can only pass something by reference as function parameter, by marking it with `&` (applies to primitives, not objects, as they are always passed by reference). If I understand you correct, this means, that neither option is good and instead I should use a `Closure` and apply it with `array_map`? But isn't that the same as option 1 in the end, just that it has to do multiple function calls (set up a call frame and tear it down afterwards)?

Comment: Well, it's only a phrasing. I clearly meant your second example. Just don't use it. Always make your parameters explicit.

Comment: Alright. Could you elaborate on why it's bad? Assuming the size of the array doesn't change, shouldn't all the data still fit in it's original place, thus no memory fragmentation, etc. occurs. (Maybe as additional information, in my case the array consists only of Objects, if that makes a difference)

Comment: Like I said, the drawbacks are the same as with using a global. Your array has been changed but you have no idea why- you just sent it to a function! An explicit code should be always preferred to some obscure magic